# IIS: front end server not connecting to website

Tags: iis, web-applications

I am newer to IIS so please forgive my ignorance. Here is my situation. I have a backend server that resides on ip xx.xx.xx.175 from here I have all my code and IIS installed here. I created a website and can access it just fine using localhost:3000. When I go to the frontend server which resides at xx.xx.xx.174 I cannot connect to the site using the URL.

I have updated the bindings, I have updated the firewall rules, I have also used netsh http add iplisten  and I still cannot connect to the site. I am not sure where else to go from here as all of my Google searching lead me to the same things.

Comment: You updated a lot, but why not share screen shots and show us? We don't have the magic to see your screen if you think twice.

Comment: @LexLi I will get those on here when I wake up tomorrow. I had to work late on another project but when I get online I will be sure to upload those

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added the ip address in the host file:

1. Open your text editor in Administrator mode.
2. In the text editor, open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.
3. Add the IP Address and hostname. Example: `192.10.10.5 testserver.com`.
4. Save the changes.

Comment: That was one step that I left out that I already did. Updating the host file was actually the first thing I did.

Comment: When you cannot connect to the site using the URL, did you get any error messages?